# Use of macro with condition in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macros

I have Below micro at objective-c
at my .pch

```
#define VERSIONCHECK 10
```

How to use it at swift ?

```
#if VERSIONCHECK > 1
   //do something    
#else
    //do nothing
#endif
```

to use in my interface for define view etc

```
@interface TestAppVC ()
{
#if VERSIONCHECK > 1
    UIView *someview;
#else
    //do nothing
#endif

}
```

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for a compile-time or a runtime check?

Comment: need run time check , to add condition according to it

Comment: There are 2 things in the question. Defining macro. Using macro. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Yes I do above code  in objective-c,its working fine , unable to use in swift as no #define here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Macros* (`#define`) doesn't exist explicitly in *Swift*. Use **Stored** and **Computed** properties to get that working.

```
let VERSIONCHECK = 10

var isVersionGreaterThanOne: Bool {
    return VERSIONCHECK > 1
}
```

**Usage:**

```
class TestAppVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if Constants.isVersionGreaterThanOne {
            //create the view here...
            let someView = UIView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can I define it in .pch ? for common use in all class ? or have to write in each class to use it ?

Comment: You can create a class Constants and add the properties to it as static. And use it like `Constants.isVersionGreaterThanOne`

Comment: also according to my check in question I add UIView in my interface how I do that now? 

#if VERSIONCHECK > 1
    UIView *someview;
#else
    //do nothing
#endif